# Реализация сравнения с null в MS SQL и в Oracle. Различие

Tags: sql, sql-server

Врно ли, что реализация сравнения отличается в этих субд? Например для оракла будет справедливо:

```
create table test_ak ( f1 number);
insert into test_ak values (1);
insert into test_ak values (null);
select count(*) from test_ak where f1 != 1;
COUNT(*)
--------
0
```

А справедливо ли это для MS SQL server?

Comment: Для любого SQL-сервера верно утверждение, что любое сравнение с NULL (кроме null-safe compare, если таковое есть, или если иное поведение специально и явно задано настройками) даёт в результате NULL, которое интерпретируется как FALSE.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22a077/1

Comment: Различий быть не может. поведение NULL оговорено стандартами и как ни удивительно, все СУБД в этом вопросе их придерживаются. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NULL_(SQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что касается чисел - реализация идентичная.
Различия есть со строковыми типами - в MS SQL пустая строка и NULL в строковом поле - это разные значения, т.е. если к полю с пустой строкой применить условие is null, такая запись возвращена не будет. Oracle же при этом заменяет пустое значение строки на NULL, поэтому такая запись будет возвращена.